# What Are The Reasons For Bit Shifting A Float Before Sending It Via A Network

Tags: networking, bit-shift

I work with Unity and C# - when making multiplayer games I've been told that when it comes to values like positions that are floats, I should use a bit shift operator on them before sending them and reverse the operation on receive. I have been told this not only allows for larger numbers values and is capable of maintaining floating point precision which may be lost. However, if I do not have to, I do not wish to run this operation every time I receive a packet unless I have to. Though the bottle necks seem to be the actual parsing of the bytes received. Especially without message framing and attempting to move from string to byte array. (But that's another story!)

My question are:

Are these valid reason to undergo the operation? Are they accurate statements?
If not should I be running bit shift ops on my floats?
If I should, what are the real reasons to do it?

Any additional information would be most appreciated.

One of the resourcesI'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: Main reasons: normalization and endianness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski - As in, on different operation systems the floating point value may be different and present different values on different machines?

Comment: Yes, floating point can be endianess dependent too

Comment: Thanks. Are there any other reason? If you want to put it as the answer I'll upvote.

Comment: I posted regular answer. Endianness is a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reasons for going back and forth to/from network byte order is to combat [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) caused problems, mainly to ensure each byte of multi byte values (long, int but also floats) is read and written in the way giving the same results regardless of architecture. This issue can be theoretically ignored if you are sure you are exchanging data between systems using the same endianness, but that's rather bad idea from very beginning as you are simply creating unneded [technological debt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) and keep unjustified exceptions in the code ("It all works BUT on the same endianness only. What can go wrong?").

Depending on your app architecture you can rewrite the packet payload/data  once you receive it and then use that version further in the code. Also note that you need to encode the data again prior sending it out.

Comment: So it does not serve the purpose of allowing values larger than 65536 and if I run a bitwise operation before send and after receive the environment it's run on will convert it to a float with the proper endian? Sorry if I'm being redundant, I just want to make sure.

Comment: No, because endianess is about byte order not byte count. You got still i. E. 16 bits before and after - it's just a matter of handing it right

Comment: So if you need more than 65535 then you need more bytes than 2.for the value, like C#'s `uint` or `ulong`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types